# For loop not breaking

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I write my code so that if any of the `if` condition is met, `for` loop breaks. I also want to make sure that it does not check any other `if` statements or `else if`.

```
   //for loop to print out the specific user names 
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.size(); i++) {

        //if statement to check input and set the method requirements to 0
        if (checkInput()) {

            //if users name is found and the customers totalpoints are 
            //greater than 5000 run this if statement and print out name and bonus and end for loop
            if (personName.equals(customerList.get(i).customerName)
                    && (customerList.get(i).totalPoints >= 5000)) {

                outputArea.append(personName + "'s Total Points are:"
                        + customerList.get(i).totalPoints + "  Bonus:1000");

                break;
                //if the users name is found but they dont have over 5000 points run this statement 
                //and end for loop
            } else if (personName.equals(customerList.get(i).customerName)) {
                outputArea.append(personName + "'s Total Points are:"
                        + customerList.get(i).totalPoints + "  Bonus:0");
                break;
            } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: You've already done exactly that with the `break` statements.

Comment: For a "cleaner" way to break a for loop (where you are sure to end this loop only and not another), you can use `i = customerList.size();`, or introduce a boolean in the condition that you set to `false`: `for (int i = 0; i < customerList.size() && stay; i++)`. It will not break immediately though, only after the current loop cycle.

Comment: Also `else if` is not checked if any previous `if` was `true`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "the for loop ends":

If you want to exit the whole for-loop use

```
break;
```

As that's already in your code i guess you want to skip to the next iteration of the loop. For that use

```
continue;
```